# filter Firebase data Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to store info that will be presented in a table view. This is a screenshot of the database:

[image]

I am trying to only add media from a certain "createdBy uid":

```
    func fetchMyMedia() {
        let ref = DatabaseReference.media.reference()
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "createdBy/uid").queryEqual(toValue: "Cdxbj1iCZUNxWRbIBllBxKqXh5P2")

        query.observe(.value, 
                      with: { snapshot in
                          for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                              self.myMedia.insert(childSnapshot as! Media, at: 0)
                              let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                          }
                      })
    }
```

"myMedia" is an array of type Media

I'm getting an error that I cannot cast value of type FIRDataSnapshot  to XXXXXX.Media. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

in case it helps, without listing my entire Model class, this is how I get all the info unfiltered...

```
    extension Media {
        class func observeNewMedia(_ completion: @escaping (Media) -> Void) {
            DatabaseReference.media.reference().observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                let media = Media(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
                completion(media)
            })
        }
```

and then...

```
    func fetchMedia() {
            Media.observeNewMedia { (media) in
                if !self.media.contains(media) {
                    self.media.insert(media, at: 0)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: snapshot is a  dictionary with [String : AnyObject] not Media Type you can use some sort of Dictionary to model deserialiser to type cast back to model.

Comment: Or instead of converting the snapshot to a dictionary, use `childSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "caption").value as! NSString` to access the individual properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    func fetchMyMedia() {
        let ref = DatabaseReference.media.reference()
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "createdBy/uid").queryEqual(toValue: "Cdxbj1iCZUNxWRbIBllBxKqXh5P2")

       query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

                let media = Media(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
                self.myMedia.insert(media, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
```